# LOAD XML DATA TO MYSQL (MYSQL VERSION 5.1)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i want to store data from a XML file to the mysql 
am using mysql version 5.1.56

the XML file Structure is

```
<STORY>
<BYFILE>abcd</BYFILE>
<STORYID>1234</STORYID>
</STORY>
```

how can i save the data ie abcd and 1234 to the database

Comment: Have a look at this Data Import tool (XML format) - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the data from xml to php.

You can parse the data to parse check the following link:

[Xml to php array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parser_expat.asp)

Or you can try this code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

this will parse the data into php.

Comment: it shows simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "0"

Comment: as you see you should pass file that contains the xml data if that is anywhere then pass with full path.

Answer (score 0):

Here your requirement says "i want to store data from a XML file to the mysql am using mysql version 5.1.56". So I got two solutions.

1. You can directly import XML data to your mySQL database using some 3rd party tools such as navicat
2. You can use PHP as the middle agent and read the XML file with simplexml_load_file and save data to your database accordingly.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: am getting 
simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "0"